# Disable Thunderbolt ports in macOS Mojave to mitigate the Thunderclap vulnerabilities

Tags: macos, applescript, mojave, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Due to the Thunderclap vulnerabilities we need to disable all Thunderbolt interfaces (except the DisplayPort signal). We are using Late 2015 iMac running macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Currently there is a secondary Apple Display connected via a Thunderbolt Port.

I already tried to unload kernel extension by running:

```
$ sudo kextunload com.apple.iotkit.IOThunderboltFamily
$ sudo kextunload -b com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.4
$ sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOThunderboltFamily.kext
```

I found the right process using:

```
$ kextstat -a

 75    3 0xffffff7f8198f000 0xf000     0xf000     x86_64             com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily (5.6.4) C6AEB6E6-AFFC-355F-8073-73E21E8BC49E <65 12 6 5 3 1>
```

Every time I try to unload, I get the messages that there was a problem terminating the services.

Comment: You seem to be confusing some things. Is your intent to stop "data transfers from mass storage devices" or to guard against "security issues (Thunderclap)"? - Those two are not the same.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. Let me set this clear. Im looking to guard the Thunderbolt Ports against security issues (Thunderclap)

Comment: Super! I have edited the question to reflect that!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to move away those kernel extensions completely. This means that they're never loaded during boot - and thus you do not have a "gap" where the computer is vulnerable during the time between boot and the time where you run the kextunload commands. In addition you do not have to deal with dependencies for unloading them.

The necessary steps are:

1) Boot the Mac in Recovery mode (boot the Mac with cmd-R pressed).

2) Open Terminal

3) Disable SIP by running:

```
  csrutil disable
```

4) Create a folder to contain the disabled extensions:

```
  mkdir /Users/<username>/ArchivedExtensions/
```

5) Move the kernel extensions you want to disable away by running:

```
  mv /System/Library/Extensions/<name>.kext /Users/<username>/ArchivedExtensions/
```

6) Re-enable SIP by running:

```
  csrutil enable
```

Note that  should be substituted with your username, and  should be substituted with the extension you want to disable. You can run the command multiple times with different names to disable more extensions.

The relevant extensions you can disable are:

- AppleThunderboltDPAdapters.kext
- AppleThunderboltEDMService.kext
- AppleThunderboltIP.kext
- AppleThunderboltNHI.kext
- AppleThunderboltPCIAdapters.kext
- AppleThunderboltUTDM.kext
- IOThunderboltFamily.kext

Answer (score 0):

I followed your steps one by one. When i'm at #5 i get the Message that the directory

```
 /System/Library/Extensions/<name>.kext: Read-Only file system
```

Is there any possibility, that i use root to mv the Drivers?
Right now i cant move the .kext Files.

Comment: Yes, you need to use root to move .kext files. `sudo mv path/from path/to`